# Simulate clearing cookies after each request in a Python unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, flask, python-unittest

I need to write a unit test to determine if a rate limiting method works even if the user clears cookies after each request.  The existing rate limiting method uses the session to count requests.  Our security guru says this is easily bypassed by clearing cookies after each request. I don't know how to simulate a new session or clearing cookies in the unit test.  Server is Python2.7 using Flask.  Existing code:

```
def test_retry_protection(self):
    #
    prev1 = app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_COUNT']
    app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_COUNT'] = 3
    prev2 = app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_SECONDS']
    app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_SECONDS'] = 5
    username = 'retry.me'
    password = 'ke52u&%y!jfueQ'
    result = self.app.post('/add_password',
                           data=dict(username=username, password1=password,
                                     password2=password))
    assert '": "ok"' in result.data, result.data

    for x in range(app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_COUNT'] - 1):
        result = self.app.post('/update_password',
                               data=dict(username=username, password1=password,
                                         password2=password, password_old=password + 'wrong'))
        assert 'User and password not correct' in result.data, result.data

    result = self.app.post('/update_password',
                           data=dict(username=username, password1=password + 'change',
                                     password2=password + 'change', password_old=password))
    assert 'Excessive usage - wait 10 minutes to try again' in result.data, result.data
    time.sleep(app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_SECONDS'] + 1)
    result = self.app.post('/update_password',
                           data=dict(username=username, password1=password + 'change',
                                     password2=password + 'change', password_old=password))
    assert '": "ok"' in result.data, result.data
    app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_COUNT'] = prev1
    app.config['RETRY_PROTECTION_SECONDS'] = prev2
```

Comment: I do not think if the cookies are cleared their is any way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Flask.test_client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.test_client) to write unit tests you can use its `cookie_jar` attribute to access cookies:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
client = app.test_client()

client.cookie_jar.clear()
# or
client.cookie_jar.clear_session_cookies()
```

[Official documentation on CookieJar objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.